# Compilation errors occur when building code with "postcss" preprocessor

Tags: npm, sass, laravel-8, tailwind-css, postcss

I have a new project with laravel 8.

If I use the sass preprocessor in the webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

then the compilation of the code during the execution of the npm run watch command proceeds without errors.

but if I change the preprocessor to post "postcss" in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

errors occur during compilation.

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError
(1:1) C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\resources\sass\app.scss Unknown word

> 1 | import api from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
    | ^
  2 |             import content from "!!../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12[0].rules[0].use[1]!../../node_modules/postcss-loade
r/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12[0].rules[0].use[2]!../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-12[0].rules[0].use[3]!./app.scss";
  3 | 

    at processResult (C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:598:19)
    at C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:692:5
    at C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (C:\Users\webgr\laravel-dev\vue.loc\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:94:7)

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

But I need to include in the my project "Tailwindcss" it needs the "postcss" preprocessor. This is what the Tailwindcss documentation says.

What can be done to correct these errors?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);`?

Comment: @RobBiermann Yes, I tried to do what you said, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging in the code, I figured out what to do and I solved this problem by changing webpack.mix.js as follows

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/dashboard/app.js', 'public/js/dashboard')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/dashboard/app.scss', 'public/css/dashboard')
    .postCss('resources/css/dashboard/app.css', 'public/css/dashboard', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
])
    .sourceMaps();
```